# How do I put two different equations side by side in align*-enviroment?

Tags: align, amsmath

First time being in StackExchange. I am currently facing the problem of writing a complex equation like so:

[image: Complex equation, seems to be split in two halves]

I have tried recreating this equation, yet so far what I could accomplish is the left side. Here's my code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \text{I}\ 7x_1 + 3x_2 = 7 & \overset{\text{I}-3\text{II}}{\Longrightarrow}x_1=1\\
        \text{II}\ 2x_1 + x_2 = 2 & \overset{7\text{II}-2\text{I}}{\Longrightarrow}x_2=0
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

...and how it currently looks:
[image: Code above compiled]

I sadly could not recreate the right side. I am pretty new in (La)TeX, so I could be asking something really obvious.

Is there any way to recreate the right side as in the picture? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Please extend your code to a compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  That will give potential helpers something to start with, without guessing.

Comment: I have edited the question, but I can be failing to understand if my edit is correct...

Comment: Welcome! The code you upload should compile without errors. It should start with `\documentclass` and you should include any relevant `\usepackage` commands. For example, you are using (at least) `amsmath` in your code. This is what's known as a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). I added it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `aligned`, which does not place its contents on a new line. I also suggest using `\xRightarrow` (which uses the `mathtools` package) which automatically stretches to fit its contents. (A `\phantom` 0 is used to make both arrows the same length.)

Unrelated: `\mathrm` is preferable to `\text`. The former will keep the upright shape but the latter may change if the surrounding text is in italic shape. You could also use `\textup`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}
    \mathrm{I}\quad 7x_1 + 3x_2 = 7 & \xRightarrow{\phantom{0}\mathrm{I}-3\mathrm{II}}x_1=1\\
    \mathrm{II}\quad 2x_1 + x_2 = 2 & \xRightarrow{7\mathrm{II}-2\mathrm{I}}x_2=0
\end{aligned}
\Longrightarrow\frak{S}=\biggl\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}\biggr\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2
\]

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you could place the system in an `array` if you want the larger spacing in your image:

[image]

```
\[
\begin{array}{crcrcrcr}
    \mathrm{I} & 7x_1 & + & 3x_2 & = & 7 & \xRightarrow{\phantom{0}\mathrm{I}-3\mathrm{II}} & x_1=1\\
    \mathrm{II} & 2x_1 & + & x_2 & = & 2 & \xRightarrow{7\mathrm{II}-2\mathrm{I}}& x_2=0
\end{array}
\Longrightarrow\frak{S}=\biggl\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}\biggr\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2
\]
```

Comment: Is there any way to increase the spacing between the operators in equations like in the image above?

Comment: @Eversiege: I updated my solution.